# Ruby readable user agent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, user-agent

Is there a gem that translates user agent strings into "human" format...something more readily identifiable?

Example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25
```

Would translate to `OS X Safari`...or something of that sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [useragent](https://github.com/josh/useragent) ?

```
string = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5'
user_agent = UserAgent.parse(string)    
user_agent.browser
# => 'Chrome'
user_agent.version
# => '19.0.1084.56'
user_agent.platform
# => 'Macintosh'
user_agent.mobile?
# => false
```